# A probability question regarding a coin and $2$ people

Tags: probability

A coin having probability $.8$ of landing on heads is flipped. $A$ observes the result—either heads or tails—and rushes off to tell $B$. However, with probability $.4$, $A$ will have forgotten the result by the time he reaches $B$. If $A$ has forgotten, then, rather than admitting this to $B$, he is equally likely to tell $B$ that the coin landed on heads or that it landed tails. (If he does remember, then he tells $B$ the correct result.) What is the probability that $B$ is told the correct result?

That author of my book showed how to derive the supposedly correct result (and it probably is), but I am not convinced.

**My attempt**

Let $F$ denote the event that $A$ has forgotten and $C$ the event that $A$ convays the correct information to $B$.

$$P(C)=P(F)P(C\mid F)+P(F^c)\underbrace{P(C\mid F^c)}_{=1}=\frac{4}{10}P(C\mid F)+\frac{6}{10}=\frac{2P(C\mid F)+3}{5}$$

The author caims that $P(C\mid F)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$ but I'm not convinced that the probability distribution (not sure if that terminology is correct) is evenly distributed among the remaining outcomes given that the coin is not fair. Could someone argue for why it should be?

Edit: I cannot take anything for granted after learning about the Monty Hall problem anymore so I am always suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $P(C|F)=\frac 12$  even though the correct result is biased.  Assuming he has forgotten and the correct result is heads with probability $0.8$, he will announce heads $0.5$ of the time, independent of the correct result.  The chance he correctly announces heads is $0.5 \cdot 0.8=0.4$  The chance he correctly announces tails is $0.5 \dot 0.2=0.1$  The total is $0.5$, justifying the assertion.  You can use $h$ as the probability that the correct result was heads and repeat this to find he will be correct $0.5$ of the time regardless of the correct probability.  If his announcement is biased, the chance of being correct will not be independent of the underlying distribution.